# How Azure functions with service bus trigger decides how many message to be delivered to azure function when batch is enabled

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Want to know how the azure function trigger will work when the messages are continuously being delivered to service bus topic. As far as i know, the azure functions gets triggered the moment topic receives the message. Under when batch & session is enabled, will function wait for specific period of time so that the topic gets multiple message and multiple messages can be delivered to azure functions.

Comment: please share the azure function app code

Comment: Do the `host.json` documentation help you at all? They mention a max batch wait time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: @AndrewB thanks for sharing the article. That was the exact thing which we wanted. Will  check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messaging with SDK might be delayed for some but will not require waiting for a specific period of time, unlike [PeekLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock). Multiple messages can be delivered with batching.

**Batching:**

Batching delivers a set number of messages to the function as a single batch, allowing for processing multiple messages in one invocation. When batching is enabled, it **doesn't** wait for a specific period to accumulate messages before delivering them to the function.
The code for the Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions is taken from [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "clientRetryOptions": {
        "mode": "exponential",
        "tryTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "delay": "00:00:10.90",
        "maxDelay": "00:10:00",
        "maxRetries": 3
      },
      "prefetchCount": 100, // Adjust as needed
      "autoCompleteMessages": true,
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:05:00",
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
      "maxMessageBatchSize": 1000,
      "minMessageBatchSize": 1,
      "maxBatchWaitTime": "00:00:30"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Sessions enable joint and ordered handling of unbounded sequences of related messages. Sessions can be used in **first in, first out (FIFO)** and request-response patterns. Enabling sessions in your Service Bus queue or topic doesn't change the **triggering mechanism** for batching.